# I kept on getting Error Parsing Reference on Docker Build

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon 7.351 MB
Step 1/12 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
Error parsing reference: "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

This is what i am getting on my console.
It was completely working fine on linux but when i tried the same code on windows, i am getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `AS build`, that means you are using multistage build which starts from `Docker 17.05`, see [this](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/).

So, your need to upgrade your docker version, otherwise you will see something like next:

```
root@ip-10-23-22-89:/home/ubuntu# docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:50:17 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:50:17 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
root@ip-10-23-22-89:/home/ubuntu# docker build -t abc:1 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  21.5 kB
Step 1/1 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build
Error parsing reference: "mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build" is not a valid repository/tag: invalid reference format
```

Comment: I had 17.03 installed, and after updating to 18 i.e latest, It is working fine seamlessly.
Thank You.